# How to POST only part of full model from ASP .NET MVC razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a View with @model declared as FullModel type;

```
public class FullModel
{
    public IList<Record> SomeRecords {get;set;}
    public Record NewRecord {get;set;}
}
```

This view, renders SomeRecords, and also renders Form for posting NewRecord to controller method defined as:

```
public ActionResult CreateNew(Record record)
{
    ...
}
```

Something like this:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("CreateNew", "RecordController"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewRecord.SomeProp)
    ...
}
```

But this doesn't work, because the path starts from root `FullModel`, so the POST data becomes `NewRecord.SomeProp` and controller expects `Record` as root, the path should be `SomeProp`

What's the usual \ proper way to deal with this?

Comment: The controller method needs to be `public ActionResult CreateNew([Bind(Prefix="NewRecord")]Record model){...}` or `public ActionResult CreateNew(FullModel model){...}`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `TryUpdateModel` method.

```
public ActionResult CreateNew(FormCollection collection)
{
  Record record = new Record();
  TryUpdateModel<Record>(record, "NewRecord", collection);
  // do more stuff
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.TryUpdateModel%60%601%28%60%600,System.String,System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider%29

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use `TextBox` instead of `TextBoxFor` and define your custom name:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("CreateNew", "RecordController")) 
{
    @Html.TextBox("SomeProp", Model.NewRecord.SomeProp)
...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I would like to preserve Type safety, and refactor friendly code.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/) you should use an [Editor Template](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx), which ASP.NET MVC uses to render the editor for `NewRecord` in your case. This editor will have the correct naming.

Steps to follow:

- Under the *Views* folder, create a folder named `EditorTemplates`.
- Create a view for your sub view model (`NewRecord`).

  ```
  @model NewRecord

  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeProp)
  ```
- Use `EditorFor` to let ASP.NET MVC render the editor, using the template you've just built.

  ```
   @Html.EditorFor(x => x.NewRecord)
  ```

Comment: I got the idea, IMHO this is huge work for such a common scenario (creating new files, all this mouse clicking, switching files, etc). At first I was wondering why MVC\Razor creators didn't included a helper method like: String GetPropertyPath<TModel, TProperty>(Func<TModel, TProperty> expression) {..}, then i discovered Razor's awful Generics syntax, and the question disappeared -)

Comment: Sorry, there is no other way I am aware of instead of the other answer which has obvious drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`BindAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute_properties(v=vs.118).aspx) on the action parameter to specify the model has a prefix.